# Drawer - Call OpenDrawer method but I don't like hide the menu options of the main activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, drawer

I call "OpenDrawer" method of Drawer, but I don't like hide the menu options (icons) in the   main activity toolbar.

I set a DrawerToggle without invalidateOptionsMenu(), but with "DrawerOpen" the menu icons are hidden in the main activity toolbar

Comment: `I lunch "OpenDrawer"` - bon appetite :)

Comment: I too, but i don't like that the icons toolbar hide !!

Comment: @FernandoMontoya He was making a joke about you misspelling the word `launch`.

Comment: can you help me for the question?